# dependancy injection in asp.net mvc, images being served by .net process

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, structuremap

I don't have the code in front of my at the moment, but I am wondering if someone could answer this.

In my asp.net MVC application, I was using structuremap for dependancy injection.

And when I did this, I noticed that all requests were going through the asp.net process, even images were being served through the asp.net pipeline.

Is this normally the case or only when I used an IoC container and had to take control over object creation with structuremap?

Comment: Depend on which object you put into structure map, pls could you show how you register classes

Answer (score 1):

Normally this should have no relation to the DI framework. It's more related to whether you are using Integrated Pipeline mode or Classic Mode in IIS. It might also be the case if you have the following setting in your web.config:

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
```